# convert from time in format h.mm to minutes

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have time stored as number in an oracle database in the format hh.mm, I want to calculate the sum and then write it back in another column in the same format hh.mm using a store procedure.
Is there any function in oracle for this type of summation or I have to do it from scratch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing values in a custom format. So obviously Oracle won't a built-in function to handle it.

Doing this requires a series of steps, which could be wrapped into a user-defined function.

1. Convert the numeric column into a string.  It is important to specify the format mask, otherwise the next step will produce the wrong result
2. Use regular expressions to extract the hour and minute values from the column
3. Derive the total number of minutes with simple arithmetic
4. Derive the new total number of hours and remainder of minutes with simple arithmetic
5. Derive the final number as a pseudo-decimal value.

Here is the SQL ...

```
select hh + (mi/100) as final_result
from (
  select trunc(step3.tot_mins/60) as hh
         , step3.tot_mins - (trunc(step3.tot_mins/60)*60) as mi
  from (
      select sum((step2.hh*60)+step2.mi) as tot_mins
      from (
        with step1 as (select to_char(ctime, '00000000000.99') ctime 
                   from your_table)
        select to_number(regexp_substr(ctime, '([0-9]+)', 1,1)) as hh
               , to_number(regexp_substr(ctime, '([0-9]+)', 1, 2)) as mi
        from step1
           ) step2
    ) step3
  ) step4
/
```

... and here is [the obligatory SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2fd0/2).